# Ktor's function `staticResources` is not available on Kotlin native targets

Tags: kotlin, ktor, kotlin-native

I'm running a simple Ktor server on a Kotlin Native target.

The server should only serve a static html page. I checked the Ktor sample on delivering static content but neither `staticResources` nor `static` or `staticFiles` is available to be imported.

```kotlin
...
routing {
    staticResources("/static", "assets", index = "my_index.html") 
    // staticResources not found as function
}
...
```

What builds is e.g.:

```kotlin
embeddedServer(CIO, port = 8080) {
    routing {
        get("/") {
            call.respondText("Hi") // works
        }
    }
}.start()
```

I cannot read or see any limitation of Ktor or the CIO engine that relates to this error.

Comment: I'm not sure _why_ this is the case, but [staticResources](https://api.ktor.io/ktor-server/ktor-server-core/io.ktor.server.http.content/static-resources.html?query=fun%20Route.staticResources(remotePath:%20String,%20basePackage:%20String?,%20index:%20String?%20=%20%22index.html%22,%20block:%20StaticContentConfig%3CURL%3E.()%20-%3E%20Unit%20=%20{}):%20Route) says it's only available on the JVM.

Comment: Looking at the code, `StaticContent.kt` and `StaticContentResolution.kt` are only available in the `jvm` directory ([link](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/tree/main/ktor-server/ktor-server-core/jvm/src/io/ktor/server/http/content)). It means that they are only supported on the JVM.

This feature seems to be coupled with JVM by providing the ability to load resources from Java classpath ([link](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/main/ktor-server/ktor-server-core/jvm/src/io/ktor/server/http/content/StaticContentResolution.kt#L23-L43)).

Comment: Ah thanks you all, sadly, I cannot mark anyone of you as the answer. Nevertheless, you are amazing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**

Please see comments under the original post. `staticResource`, etc. are only supported on a JVM target.